Linux kernel module not created
I have very simple module.c file and Makefile for linux kernel module.
Makefile:
# Source files directory
SRC_DIR := src

# Get all source files
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)

# Define the target object file
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c,$(SRC_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))

#Option A
obj-m += $(OBJ_FILES)
#Option B
#obj-m += src/module.o

KERNEL_DIR_HOST=/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-163-generic/build

all:
    make -C ${KERNEL_DIR_HOST} M=${PWD} modules
clean:
    make -C ${KERNEL_DIR_HOST} M=${PWD} clean   
    @echo clean done
print:
    @echo $(obj-m)

I have option A and option B for obj-m to define the object files.
For both options make print shows the same, but for option A there is no module created.
For option A no module created:
make print
src/module.o
make all
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-163-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-163-generic'

For option B module created:
make print
src/module.o
make all
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-163-generic'
  CC [M]  /opt/work/module/src/module.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC [M]  /opt/work/module/src/module.mod.o
  LD [M]  /opt/work/module/src/module.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-163-generic'

Running more verbose make command (f.e. make --debug -f Makefile) doesn't give any more helpful information.
Any idea?

Note also, that obj-m creates separate module for every item specified. If you want to create single module from several files, then give single parameter to obj-m (e.g. obj-m += module_a.o) and specify several files in <modname>-y variable (e.g. module_a-y += $(OBJS)).
